# define two syntax regions with same pattern

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I try to extend the cmake syntax highlighting by our in-house cmake functions. For this I drafted a file to be saved in `~/.vim/after/syntax/cmake.vim`, such that one extends the default cmake syntax highlighting, as suggested in [this stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16224423/extending-javascript-syntax-highlighting-in-vim) post.

What I am struggeling with is that we use `INCLUDE_DIRS` as keyword, whereas standard cmake uses `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`, and I want the syntax highlighting to point out to a developer that they used the wrong convention for the function at hand. (Yes, I could also try to push towards fixing our inhouse style, but the general problem of what-are-possible-keywords-here would remain).

The standard cmake syntax file I'm testing against is [here](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Auxiliary/vim/syntax/cmake.vim)

So, I want

```
add_library( # this is a standard cmake function
          ....
          INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES somepath # highlight the first word here, it's spelled right
          INCLUDE_DIRS  otherpath      # don't highlight this, it's spelled wrong
 )

fancy_wrapper( # this is from the inhouse modules
           ...
           INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES   somepath   # don't highlight
           INCLUDE_DIRS otherpath)          # highlight
)
```

My understanding was that I can use in my extension the following:

```
if exists("b:current_syntax")
  if b:current_syntax != "cmake"
    finish
  endif
endif
let s:keepcpo= &cpo
set cpo&vim

syn region OurArgs start="(" end=")" contains=OurArguments

syn case match

syn keyword OurArguments contained
        \ INCLUDE_DIRS

syn case ignore

syn keyword cmakeOurs
            \ fancy_wrapper
            \ nextgroup=OurArgs

hi def link cmakeOurs Function
hi def link OurArguments ModeMsg

let &cpo = s:keepcpo
unlet s:keepcpo
```

my understanding is that `fancy_wrapper` now gets recognised as an inhouse function and the next group will be a `OurArgs` region instead of the normal `cmakeArguments`. And for the normal `add_library` the official cmake style should kick in (copy and pasting their code):

```
syn keyword cmakeCommand
...
        \ add_library
...
        \ nextgroup=cmakeArguments
```

Such that the parentheses thereafter are a `cmakeArguments` region and `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` gets recognized therein.

However, what I observe is that `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` never gets highlighted and `INCLUDE_DIRS` always gets highlighted. Using the [debugging hints here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Identify_the_syntax_highlighting_group_used_at_the_cursor)) I see that the region after `add_library` is recognized as `OurArgs` (last definition taking precedence, afaiu. instead of - what i had hoped - the `nextgroup` deciding what happens).

So my question is:

- How can I highlight different sets of keywords within parentheses regions, that all look the same in `start=` and `end=`? Is that not what `nextgroup` is good for?
- Ideally (depending how the answer on the first turns out), can I still do that without modifying kitware's cmake.vim file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Superficially, all that is missing is the `contained` attribute for the `OurArgs` definition. Without it, that may match anywhere, not just after `cmakeOurs` via the `nextgroup=`. Very often, when you explicitly ask for parsing to continue with `nextgroup`, you want that syntax to be `contained`, to avoid accidental matches elsewhere.

```
syn region OurArgs start="(" end=")" contains=OurArguments contained
```

Unfortunately, it's not that easy with the `cmake` syntax. Looking at the "competing" `cmakeArguments` region, it has this definition:

```
syn region cmakeArguments start="(" end=")"
\ contains=ALLBUT,cmakeCommand,cmakeCommandConditional,cmakeCommandRepeat,
\ cmakeCommandDeprecated,cmakeArguments,cmakeTodo
```

The problem is the `ALLBUT`, which indirectly again introduces `OurArgs` and `OurArguments` into the regular cmake block, which causes the matching that you don't want there.

Now, if `syntax/cmake.vim` were written with extension in mind, it would include an (empty) [`:help :syn-cluster`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#%3Asyn-cluster) in that `contains` clause, allowing you to add your groups to the exclusion list. As it does not, you need to override the original definition, like this:

```
syn clear cmakeArguments
syn region cmakeArguments start="(" end=")"
\ contains=ALLBUT,cmakeCommand,cmakeCommandConditional,cmakeCommandRepeat,
\ cmakeCommandDeprecated,cmakeArguments,cmakeTodo,OurArgs,OurArguments
```

With that, the coloring will only apply to the `fancy_wrapper` block.

PS: The `OurArgs` and `OurArguments` are not very expressive (hopefully just because you've obfuscated them for us), and should also start with the `cmake` prefix like the original syntax items.

Comment: I didn't so much have obfuscation in mind but rather having a minimum working example instead of a huge list of equally meaningless functions and arguments, in the large file I am using more expressive names (though naming things is hard.)

Comment: the pointer to :syn-cluster turns out very helpful!